# Parallel request on the same PHP script causes a second long delay

Tags: php, apache, request, concatenation, minify

**Background**

This is something driving me crazy for weeks. I use MrClay's PHP Minify script to minify and concatenate my JS and CSS. It works great, all my files are merged into common.css and common.js, which are virtual files, translated to link to to the script like this:

```
RewriteRule ^common.js$ /tynamic/min/?g=js [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^common.css$ /tynamic/min/?g=css [L,QSA]
```

A query string is also appended to denote a version of these files, and they have a 3 year long caching, so a person that visited my site will likely never have to download any CSS or JS on any future visit to that site (if they don't change, obviously). So far everything works.

**The problem**

Often (sadly not always), when my browser asks for these 2 files (which is done at the same time), **one of the files takes a second to get returned**. Its always the one whose request arrives later to the server, so its **usually** the one which is later in the HTML, but its not a rule.

See these screenshots:

[taken from my Firefox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x69xcgjp1dxih64/delaygate_ff.png?dl=0)

[test report by Pingdom](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c49xjoxtxbkv5nv/delaygate_pingdom.png?dl=0)

I'd be okay with the server putting the other file to a queue and proccesing it after the first one, but that doesn't take a whole second.
Few more things: **no action like concatetion or gzipping is being performed** in this case.. the script is only doing a fpassthru() of an existing pre-gzipped file. It doesn't happen all the time however.. there it gets a little bit odd, if I do a large number of consecutive pageloads, like 30 or more, it goes back to "normal" when both files are processed in a trivial time. Then when I check after some time, it is back on the second hang. **The time is always something little over a second**.

**What I already tried**

1. Putting `if($_GET["g"]=="js") exit;` right at the start of the script.

Thats right, that was of no help. The file was still delayed, outputting nothing. Just `exit;` (for both files) however works... :)

2. Timing the scripts

Both runs report minimal times (units or tens of milliseconds) of their runs, so there is no function that would delay it.

3. Different server/hosting

No help, 3 different servers and hosting providers. It is not hosting related.

4. Making a full copy of the script

So I made a copy of the full script directory to ensure both runs are made by different set of files - no help.

5. Disabling file locking nad other tweaks to script config or the script itself.

So far I didn't came up with anything :(

6. Different script - doing something else.

This was interesting, modifying the files to do something else, e.g. do a scandir and pick a file **didn't help either**. Another analysis showed, that the PHP scripts are being assigned to free CPU threads **every second**. So if there are e.g. 5 threads, and 6 scripts need to be run at once, the first 5 are done in like 10 msecs, but the 6th has to wait a whole second to even start being proccessed... Why is this happening?

**Thanks a lot in advance for any effort put in to helping me**

Comment: Are you using sessions in your scripts? If so, a session opened in one script instance will block other instances trying to access the same session. (The usual solution is to call `session_write_close` before initiating longer-running stuff.)

Comment: Thanks, but thats not the case.

Comment: can you share the code for review and debugging

Comment: You wrote, "3 different servers and hosting providers. It is not hosting related", could you please list PHP versions and web server versions from those providers?

Comment: @dkkumargoyal Code is not quite relevant. Happens with any code in the script. Just not with `exit;` however :D

@GrzegorzAdamKowalski
1. Server: nginx/1.6.2 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.14-0+deb8u1

2. Server: Apache / PHP 5.6.9

3. Server: Apache / PHP 5.6.5

DOES NOT happen on:
Server: nginx/1.2.1 / PHP 5.5.19-pl0-gentoo
But it probably has more to do with server configuration, than with sw versions...

Answer (score 4):

CBroe is probably right. If you are using sessions (session_start()), PHP will only serve one request to one client (session_id) at a time. While one request is being served, the other is queued until the session is written by the first one. The session file is locked to prevent multiple requests writing into the same session which can cause unexpected results. The session is written either when the script is finished or by calling session_write_close(). This will free your session for the next request.

However, I feel obliged to tell you that you are doing it wrong. You shouldn't be minimizing JS and CSS with PHP. Here are the reasons:

1. Using PHP for this causes unnecessary load on the server
2. The browser is still requesting the files to get a 304 response - again unnecessary load on the server and reduced user experience (these requests still take time)
3. It's hard to build a good minification tool and there's no need to reinvent the wheel. A better one is readily available.
4. There's more reasons...

I suggest you better invest your time in not writing the minification scripts, but in learning build tools (Grunt or Gulp) that will do the job for you and much more than you will want/be able to write in PHP.

In a nutshell, how this whole process works is

1. You set up your server to sent an Expires header. This will prevent the client from even requesting for changes in the files. Google for how this is done using Apache: https://www.google.com/search?q=apache+expires+htaccess&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=y12dVrqKG8KvsAHFiKjYDA
2. Set up the tools above to "build" your minified resources - concatenate multiple files, "compile" stylesheets, minify etc. So you have these built files on disk and served directly by the webserver.
3. You only set up the website to use minified resources in production. (You want to be able to debug full source in development).
4. When you deploy any changes to your website .

The skill of setting this up will come in very handy for any web developer. Also, this will free your time for building your web app itself.

Comment: No, I'm not using sessions. Filemanager is an only library that does and that runs async and only in admin. To the PHP Minify criticism: I disagree, there is no downside of that, moreover, it can be fully automated as opposed to Gulp/Grunt which need to be configured for each project, for any extra library, etc. The first 3 points: 
1. Any script would cause a load, this load is however only while dev.
2. No, it does not, Im only forcing this via F5 to simulate first pageload by a new client. Expire is 3 years, see **Background**.
3. "I use MrClay's PHP Minify script", so an available tool...

Comment: 1. Since you are doing a rewrite to a PHP file, EVERY request for these resources will invoke PHP to precess that as opposed to just serving a static file.
2. Not sure how you control the versions of the content (the query string you append), most likely it's some kind of manual adjustment. With static file you can append modification time, this can happen automaticaly.

Comment: 3. See this in the 'Warnings' section of your MrClay's PHP Minify script:
"Minify is designed for efficiency, but, for very high traffic sites, it will probably serve files slower than your HTTPd due to the CGI overhead of PHP. See the FAQ and CookBook for more info." 
This was my point.

Comment: Anyway, if you could post a link to your page in action and paste the code of the minification php script, maybe we could solve your specific problem.

Comment: 1. only at first pageload, otherwise there is no request.
2. yes, its a checksum created from mod. time
3. aware of that, my webs are not traffic heavy, so I prefer a fully automated solution, where everything in css/less/js folders is being fully taken care of, without any supervision. Adding a JS lib is a drag n drop action.
Ok, I will link it, but as I said, this problem doesn't appear always, sometimes it's completely OK, 5 mins later is not.. and so on.
[link](http://cherokees.cz/)
I appreciate your effort, thank you!

Comment: I have checked out the link and couldn't replicate it. Another reason could be is that you have this same website open in another tab and it is doing a lengthy ajax request at the same time you are reloading the page in the first tab?

Comment: Well it happened also on a pingdom test (2nd screenshot). I did [another one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w5c3jjofv4xkcem/Screenshot%20%2830%29.png?dl=0), here it goes again..

Comment: It has nothing in common with the minification scripts.. its a server thing.. I just did a multi_curl ping to request 51 times at once a random from the site. [Here is the result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u2dgmsfq0m5gx5l/51requests_wedos_nolimit.htm?dl=0). The one second lags can be clearly seen. Seem to appear every 5 requests, probably because the hosting declares 5 PHP threads. Ok, 5 threads, but why the lag?

Comment: Seems you are limited to max 5 server threads at all. Look at how are your  images from */files/img/slider_1* folder loaded. Stupid thing to do, but will you try to put this script in two different folders?

Comment: 5 is the browser's limit. Diffrerent for some browsers, but it won't send more than this limit of concurrent requests to a domain.

Comment: The hosting provider claims that there are exactly 5 PHP threads to use. Its not a browser thing - same effect achieved via CURL and via pingdom test. "will you try to put this script in two different folders?" - already did - see number 4 in things I have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not resolved, however I have found a hosting provider with which this problem simply does not appear. It is then a hosting issue and it has to be something with how it assigns PHP threads to requests - it seems like my old hosts were doing this ONLY with one-second ticks. Thats all I know now.